# How to generate combinations of k numbers from a list of N numbers(where N could be >>> k)?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been given a list of 'N' numbers for example [1,2,5,7,7,8] and I want to generate all combinations of 'k' elements (Let's say k = 2).
For k = 2 solution would be (1,2), (1,5), (1,7) and so on giving a total combination of C(6, 2).
I don't want to use itertools.combinations because N could be as big as 10^5 and that could make the code really slow.
Could you please come out with some efficient code in python without using any kind of libraries as mentioned above?